# Java- JTable not showing gridlines

Tags: java, swing

I have displayed a JTable in my JPanel.The JTable is inside a scrollpane.
The only problem is the gridlines are not showing up.I tried to use this line of code but it didn't work.

```
table.setShowGrid(true);
```

Below is a picture: Note there are no gridlines[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the grid is not white? Try `JTable.setGridColor()` to change its color.

Comment: Oh thanks.The grid was just white

Comment: You can change the grid color all tables as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13779735/230513).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Does having an etched border make a difference?

```
table.setBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED));
```

EDIT:

The default colour of grid-lines seems to be white:

```
table.setGridColor(Color.BLUE)
```

Comment: what about setting the background color?  Maybe the grid lines are white? :)

Comment: Yes @Aqua just metioned that to me in the comments.

Answer (score 11):

```
table.setShowHorizontalLines(true);
table.setShowVerticalLines(true);
```

Comment: that's exactly the same as setShowGrid(true); Anyway, the issue already was resolved and turned out to have been unrelated to showing (or not) the grid lines ... please read earlier answers and their comments before posting your own :-)

Comment: This was helpful for me. Thank you. Although, I don't know what setting this property in NetBeans GUI Designed didn't work.